# How to reorder columns in a Pandas dataframe individually by row, so that for each row, the columns are in descending order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have local election data that I have cleaned such that each column represents a town, and each column represents a candidate and how many votes they got in the election. The columns are named by the order in which the candidate appeared on the ballot, not by who got the most votes. But I want each row's columns to to be ordered based on who got the most votes. Below is a sample of my DataFrame:

```
town         cand_1 cand_2  cand_3   cand_4   
                                                              
town_1       0.64    0.24    0.12    NaN   
town_2       0.21    0.47    0.31    0.01    
town_3       0.08    0.12    0.75    0.05    
town_4       0.56    0.30    0.14    NaN
```

As you can see, candidate 3 got the most votes in town 3 and candidate 2 got the most in town 2, but they are third and second, respectively, in their rows. The desired output is as follows:

```
town         cand_1 cand_2  cand_3   cand_4   
                                                              
town_1       0.64    0.24    0.12    NaN   
town_2       0.47    0.31    0.21    0.01    
town_3       0.75    0.12    0.08    0.05    
town_4       0.56    0.30    0.14    NaN
```

How can I sort each row's columns in descending order so that the first row in each column is the candidate who got the most votes?

I tried doing it in Excel -- I highlighted each row and sorted ascending.

**EDIT**

A commenter pointed out that the names of the columns now have no meaning. I should clarify: I care only about the distribution of votes in a town, not the identity of cand_1, cand_2, etc. (I do, in fact care about the identity of the winner, but that comes from a different dataset). So the column names in the desired output dataframe should be different; or alternatively, cand_1 refers to the top vote-getter in their town.

**EDIT**

Found a solution using built-in Python functions:

```
hh=[]

for i in results_2008_list:
    cands=[i[4], i[7], i[10], i[13], i[16], i[19], i[22],
                              i[25], i[28], i[31], i[34]]
    hh.append([i[2], i[3], max(cands), sorted(cands, reverse=True)[1],
              sorted(cands, reverse=True)[2], sorted(cands, reverse=True)[3],
              sorted(cands, reverse=True)[4], i[i.index(max(cands))+1],
              i[i.index(max(cands))+2]])
```

This solution also gives me the name/party of the winning candidate.

Comment: You realise that the values now lost all their meaning? I mean, in your original dataframe, `cand_2` had 47% of the votes in `town2`, but in your final dataframe `cand_2` now has 31% in `town2`.

Comment: Fair. I think I did a poor job representing the output I wanted. I don't care about who `cand_1` and `cand_2`, etc. are; I just care about the distribution of votes in each town. I wanted `cand_1` to represent the top-earning candidate in a given town. So in the second df, `cand_1` should correspond to the top earning candidate in a given town. Using the solution with lists, I was able to get the top five vote-earners in each column (each element in the list `cands` is the pct of votes a candidate got).

Comment: I know you said you found an answer but it seems hard to maintain. Could you not do something like: `df[['the', 'cand', 'cols]] = df.apply(lambda x: x.values.sort(reverse=True), result_type='expand', axis=1)`